# Alternative for 'create shapes from vector layer' for edit possibilities in Ai

Tags: after-effects

How to keep editing possibilities in Illustrator after the Ai file is used in After Effects?

I use the Lottie files Bodymovin plugin to export my animations to JSON files for use in mobile apps and websites. After creating shapes from the vector layer (Ai layer), I can't edit the illustration in Ai and get this change in my AE animation (just as is possible using regular Ai layers-not converted to shape layers).

Answer (score 2):

The Overlord plugin can help with this.

https://www.battleaxe.co/overlord/

It can convert shapes in AI to parametric shapes in AE.